# Check duplicate using SQL before adding new asset

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have table asset following this:

```
id  status  revision  EAN
-------------------------
1   Published    0     1
1   Published    1     2
1   Deleted      2     3
2   Published    0     4
2   Draft        1     5
```

Before adding new asset, I want to check EAN in table that if asset had status Deleted, EANs of this asset can be reused (it means 1, 2, 3 can be used for new asset) and otherwise, I can not use ean in table (4, 5 can not be used).

I used count in SQL to check if >0 -> duplicate :

```
select count(*) 
from Asset a 
where a.ean = '1' 
  and a.id <> 0 
  and a.status != 'Deleted'
  and a.revision = (select max(a1.revision) 
                    from Asset a1 
                    where a1.id = a.id)
```

but it's not right for case which asset had not status Deleted.

Can anyone give me some feedback?

Please help me.
Thanks

Comment: Your query and your sample data don't match up...  Nevertheless, can you supply your expected results?

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: my expected result is ean is unique for each assets but asset had status Deleted, EANs of this asset can be reused (it means 1, 2, 3 can be used for new asset)

Answer (score 0):

I think, your query mixed up something. You where counting only the exact line with your EAN you were searching. You can count all rows with the matching id from your EAN like this:

```
select count(*) from Asset
where id = (
select id 
from Asset a 
where a.EAN = 1)
and status='Deleted'
```

You can even add your check for the last revision like this:

```
and revision = (select max(revision) from Asset WHERE id=
(
select id 
from Asset a 
where a.EAN = 1
))
```

Answer (score 0):

i'm done with sql:
`select count(*) from Asset a where a.ean=? and a!=? and not exist(select * from Asset a1 where a1.id = a.id and a.status ='Deleted').`
Thanks all.